# Dropdown Menu is closing too fast on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover

My dropdown menu is closing quickly on hover I can't touch it , but  on click my menu is staying opened. Margin is necessary.

```
 <div class="container mt-5 pt-5 ">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link text-danger" href="#" id="Dropdown" role="button" 
    data-toggle="dropdown">HOVER IT</a>
            <div  class="dropdown-menu  mt-5" aria-labelledby="Dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
            </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>

  CSS:
 .navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  transition-delay: 5s;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/booyr/pen/wvwMxvX

Comment: You should add a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) code or put it in the [codepen](https://codepen.io) so everyone can see what you working on

Comment: take a look please, it's on codepen now

Comment: You are missing what [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) that is being transition and as far as I know you can't transition `display: block;`. The spacing between the hover element and the child also making it difficult to navigate, have a look [tutorial on css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/) or [check the code](https://codepen.io/una/pen/RMmogp/)

Comment: it doesn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;** and when will be hover then you need to add **opacity:1; visibility: visible;**.. then your dropdown will be slow show and hide.

for example:

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity:1; visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav li > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity:0; visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: 3s;
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happened, the dropdown menu disappeared totally. It's not the right way, please take a look again!

Comment: please remove **display: block**. then this will be show and hide slow.. Kindly mark it as answer if it solved your problem.. THANKS

Comment: I try it without display: block and nothing happened!

Comment: this is working.. you need to remove some transition. please set **transition: .3s;** this transition

Comment: Please edit your answer and show me the working example, I tried everything and nothing at all.

Comment: please remove your all css and add this css:  `.navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity:1; visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav li > .dropdown-menu {
  opacity:0; 
    visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: .2s;
    display:block;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    transition-delay: 5s; <----- Here you can change the speed of the menu quite simply
}
```

Comment: yes, I know but it's not working with display:block, I mean transition-delay is useless in this case